# Assigning parent to Object

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some difficulties assigning the Parent.
The result after running the program is as such:

```
1   
    3
    Apple   
    3
    Orange  
2   
    3
    Apple   
    3
    Orange  
3
    3
    Apple   
    3
    Orange
```

The desirable result is:

```
1   
    1
    Apple   
    1
    Orange  
2   
    2
    Apple   
    2
    Orange  
3
    3
    Apple   
    3
    Orange
```

I do not understand why the Object's parent was assigned to the same Object because

```
Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName) = Layer2.Child(FruitName)
```

should be able to assign a brand new

```
Layer2.Child(FruitName)
```

into

```
Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName)
```

Where did I go wrong???

```
Sub Parent_Test()

Dim Main As SubTree
Dim Layer2 As SubTree

Set Main = New SubTree
Set Layer2 = New SubTree

Layer2.Child("Apple").Name = "Apple"
Layer2.Child("Orange").Name = "Orange"

For PackerNum = 1 To 3

    For Each FruitName In Layer2.Children

        Main.Child(PackerNum).Name = PackerNum
        Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName) = Layer2.Child(FruitName)
        Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName).Parent = Main.Child(PackerNum)

    Next FruitName

Next PackerNum

Print_SubTree Main, 0

End Sub


Function Print_SubTree(SubTree As SubTree, Optional ByVal LayerCount As Byte)
'This Function prints the SubTree Recursively

If SubTree.ChildrenCount = 0 Then
    If Not SubTree.Parent Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print String(LayerCount, vbTab) & SubTree.Parent.Name
    End If
    Debug.Print String(LayerCount, vbTab) & SubTree.Name
Else
    If Not SubTree.Parent Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print String(LayerCount, vbTab) & SubTree.Parent.Name
    End If
    Debug.Print String(LayerCount, vbTab) & SubTree.Name

    LayerCount = LayerCount + 1
    For Each Key In SubTree.Children

        Print_SubTree SubTree.Child(Key), LayerCount

    Next Key

End If

End Function
```

My Class Module is as follows:

```
Private pChild As Object
Private pParent As SubTree

Public Name As String
Public InstanceName As String

Public Property Get Child(ByVal KeyString As Variant) As SubTree
    If Not pChild.Exists(KeyString) Then
        Dim objChild As New SubTree
        pChild.Add KeyString, objChild
    End If
    Set Child = pChild(KeyString)
End Property

Public Property Let Child(ByVal KeyString As Variant, ByVal objChild As SubTree)
    pChild.Add KeyString, objChild
End Property

Public Property Get Parent() As SubTree
    Set Parent = pParent
End Property

Public Property Let Parent(ByRef objParent As SubTree)
    Set pParent = objParent
End Property


Public Property Get Children() As Variant
    Children = pChild.Keys
End Property

Public Property Get ChildrenCount() As Variant
    ChildrenCount = pChild.Count
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pChild = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set pName = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pChild = Nothing
    Set pName = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the same `Layer2` object in each case, so you're actually changing the parent of the same children each time. To get the output you want, you'd need a new `layer2` object inside the loop - for example:

```
Sub Parent_Test()

Dim Main As SubTree
Dim Layer2 As SubTree

Set Main = New SubTree

For PackerNum = 1 To 3
    Set Layer2 = New SubTree

    Layer2.Child("Apple").Name = "Apple"
    Layer2.Child("Orange").Name = "Orange"

    For Each FruitName In Layer2.Children

        Main.Child(PackerNum).Name = PackerNum
        Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName) = Layer2.Child(FruitName)
        Main.Child(PackerNum).Child(FruitName).Parent = Main.Child(PackerNum)

    Next FruitName

Next PackerNum

Print_SubTree Main, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I have another small issue though. Layer2 was actually Initialize by scanning an excel sheet so it doesn't make sense to scan the whole sheet again so that i can assign it to the 2nd Main.

Is there another way around this? like maybe assign it to a dummy and then assigning the dummy to the Main?

Comment: @FlyFlyWing Depends what you're doing really. You could use a collection of Parents rather than just one, or create a method of the class that essentially clones itself by copying all it's children to a new instance.